# manipulating an array giving weird behavior in angular 5.2

Tags: javascript, angular, immutability

[image]

In the above gif, it renders 3 item first and then I removed the second item and I added another new item with `Add New Item`.

**When I remove an item from the list and then add an item again it renders partially (before the removal index it render properly but after the removal index it renders without any value)**

**code:**

I've a an array which contains list of item that I want to render:

```
items = [
  {project_id: 'a'},
  {project_id: 'b'},
  {project_id: 'c'}
]
```

My method to add a new item in list:

```
  newItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    items = [...items, {project_id: ''}];
  }
```

Remove method to remove item from the list:

```
removeItem(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault();
    items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Here is my view html:

```
<div class="fields" *ngFor="let item of items; index as i;">
    <div class="four wide field">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.project_id" [name]="'project' + i" placeholder="Project ID">
    </div>
    <div class="one wide field">
      <a (click)="removeItem($event, i)" href="#">remove</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="newItem($event)" class="ui button">Add New Item</button>
```

Comment: That gif is somewhat unclear. Do you have a working fiddle?

Comment: I don't know how works if not use "this.item" to reference to items. Anyway use this.item.push({project_id:''}) to add a item and this.items.splice(index,1) to remove